# Re build next app when changing files (using express as server)

Tags: express, next.js, nodemon

I'm using Next.js with Express.js. Basically, express take care of all the routing instead of Next.js.

What I need for development, is that when a file changes, next.js re build their app and then reload the express server, so I can see my changes in the browser without manually building next app.

Using nodemon only does not work because it just reload express, but does not build next application.

Comment: What's your current nodemon configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was that I was using nodemon with `NODE_ENV=production`, looking something like this `NODE_ENV=production nodemon src/server.js`.

Removing the production environment solved the problem. With just `nodemon src/server.js` next it's being built and the server reloaded after that.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something in a similar vein in the past using [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch).
It's cross-platform but pretty well supported and has a plethora of options. Not having specifics of what commands you need to run in your very own case, a general case would be (for *nix-like platforms, adapt as needed):

```
fswatch -0 next_project_path | while read -d "" event \
   do \
     // ${event} will contain info on what happened fs-wise
     ... steps you need to run in rebuilding your next app...
     [...]
     ... steps you need to run to reload your express server...
   
   done
```

Since every new event will trigger the series of commands and that could represent a problem due to the fact that the previous execution might not be finished, what I did at the time was implement [something along these lines](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch/issues/93#issuecomment-141841329) whereas all pids involved in the previous run would be killed before starting the newer one.

```
reload_project() {
  # ... reload next ...
  # ... reload express ...
}
fswatch ts |

while read; do
    [...]

    
    pids=$(ps -ef | grep -E "next|express|whatever" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')

    
    if [ -n "$pids" ]; then
        kill -9 $pids &> /dev/null
    fi

    reload_project &
done
```